# F# Console application can't be created from VisualStudio

Tags: visual-studio, f#, visual-studio-2017

I have installed `VisualStudio 2017` community. And searching a way to create a `F#` console application. In VisualStudio 2015 there was `F#` console application in create menu, but in VS 2017 there is no `F#`, only `C#` and `VB`.

[image: vs 2017 doesn't contain F#]

As you can see in screen shot `F#` langauge support was installed along with `VS`:

[image]

Also i checked `F#` checkbox for console applications during the installation:
[image]

How to create `F`# console application in `VS 2017` ?

Comment: I recommend https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/03/14/announcing-nightly-releases-for-the-visual-f-tools/

Comment: @CaringDev thanks, i've installed VS F# Tools also. But how this tool can help in creation of F# console app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

reinstalling vs tools (in cmd):

> vsixinstaller /uninstall:VisualFSharp

or do the same thing manually:
`Tools->Extensions and Updates` search for `VisualFSharp` and press `uninstall`

After uninstalling, `F#` cnosole project will be available again. And in general, it is possible to instal VisualFSharp again, `F#` cnosole project shouldn't disappear.